# Creating a REST webserver with security

Tags: java, rest, webserver

I am very new to creating webservers - and I have had several goes at trying to understand them and write a quick webserver, but it's never quite 'clicked'.  At the moment I am under the impression that REST would be most suitable for my purposes (I will explain later).

Can anyone either show me a basic code example in Java (using Tomcat Apache) or a tutorial resource to show how a webserver:

- Can be used for security - i.e. pass in some kind of value to identify the client - from their the webserver will either deny or grant access to the client dependant on some criteria - maybe a lookup list.
- Once the client is successfully accepted they will be allowed to pass in some more values to the webserver that will be used to write a row in a database table.

Many thanks.

PS - I would have thought there might have been soemthing that comes with Eclipse Ganymede? If someone can confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also suggest that you look at [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to write restful resources in Java is via the JAX-RS standard. So I'd recommend you download [Jersey which is the JAX-RS reference implementation](http://jersey.java.net/) and check out its examples; its got lots of them. Take an example for a spin then try hacking it to do what you like.

BTW JAX-RS can be run inside any Servlet engine - you just build a WAR and deploy it (there are examples in the Jersery samples) - though Jersey also comes with a small lightweight web server you can use too which is a little easier to use - again there are examples in the distro of this.